# Lubuntu; switch between screens on a time loop

Tags: python, lubuntu, workspace

Im going to a conference and I want to set my laptop to cycle between the four standard workspaces/screens on an automated time loop.

I can do a bit of python, so thats a good answer for me, I guess it will be something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import time

while True:
    subprocess.call()
    time.sleep(10)
```

I just dont know what to have that subprocess.call() to actually do to cycle through screens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK then 'wmctrl' was my answer, if you dont have it already

```
apt-get install wmctrl
```

To see your workspace setup

```
wmctrl -d
```

So my little python script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import time

while True:
    subprocess.call(['wmctrl', '-s', '0'])
    time.sleep(10)
    subprocess.call(['wmctrl', '-s', '1'])
    time.sleep(10)
    subprocess.call(['wmctrl', '-s', '2'])
    time.sleep(10)
    subprocess.call(['wmctrl', '-s', '3'])
    time.sleep(10)
```

'-s' tells wmctrl to go to a workspace and 0-3 are my available workspaces.